# Live Transcoding & Streaming

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, transcoding

My client has a requirement where he needs me to transcode a source file into a proxy with a unique burn in on it per playback.

For the proxy I will be using ffmpeg, nothing fancy, but ideally the users can play back the file as it is being transcoded since it may take up to several minutes to complete the transcoding.

Another restriction is that the player does not support HLS and other live streaming options and can only accept MP4s as a source.

Any ideas/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have conflicting requirements. mp4 is VERY poorly suited for live streaming. It is 'possible' to create a fake `moov` and have the player perform byte ranges. But it is very inefficient. You really need a player or platform that supports streaming formats such as fmp4 (fragmented mp4/dash) hls, ts, flv, rtmp, rtc, etc.